# Mui Accordion change collapse direction

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, accordion

I'm currently using the Mui Accordion component ([Link](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-accordion/))  in my project. I'm curious if anyone knows whether it's possible to configure the direction in which the Accordion opens. Instead of the default vertical (up and down) opening, I'd like it to open horizontally from the side.

If there's an alternative approach to achieve this layout, please feel free to share your suggestions. Your input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be better served by the [Drawer](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-drawer/) component, which can be configured to open in any direction.